# Scaled resolutions listed in nvidia-settings cannot be displayed properly

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution

I was using a Dell desktop equipped with a NVIDIA NVS310 card and when trying to set to any of the "scaled" resolutions listed in nvidia-settings, the display did not get scaled properly. Instead, it was "cropped" to fit the said resolution. Tried other NVIDIA graphics cards like Quadro P4000 and P5000 and got the same results.

Scaled resolutions in nvidia-settings

[image: scaled resolutions in nvidia-settings]

Cropped desktop

[image: cropped desktop]

Is this a limitation in Unity? Is there a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a limitation of Unity. Scaled resolutions in nvidia-settings is software scale which does not change the physical resolution. So Unity didn't recognize the screen dimensions has been changed and kept rendering on the original dimensions. Unity can recognize the resolution change if you select non-scaled resolution.

The resolution list in u-s-d is different to nvidia-settings's list. The u-s-d does not support such scaled resolutions.

Comment: Could you explain what u-s-d is please?